# Prevent table refreshing on parent state change when selecting rows

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a table in server data mode using material ui data grid.

Now, we're adding checkboxes for selecting rows.
In order to allow the user to keep selecting rows after page change we need to lift the state to the parent

const [selectionModel, setSelectionModel] = React.useState([]);

This works but now the table refreshes every time user clicks on a row, because the prop selectionModel changes.

Is there any way around it?

this is how I pass the props to the table:

checkboxSelection={true} onSelectionModelChange={handleSelectionModelChange} selectionModel={selectionModel} keepNonExistentRowsSelected

Comment: this might be helpful https://alexsidorenko.com/blog/react-list-rerender/